# How to pass value from model to select input use laravel eloquent

Tags: php, html, tags, laravel-8

I have model with attributes category
i want pass 1 data to select tag

Category option

```
Category
1. Fruit
2. Vegetables
3. Meat
```

example data

| name | category |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 |

how i can pass apple category to select tag

```
<select class="form-control form-select" name="category" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">fruit</option>
  <option value="2">vegetables</option>
  <option value="3">meat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you want dynamic categories in select tag?

Comment: @KUMAR no i just want set selected option with data that i have

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t provide much details but I guess you meant something like this:

In your controller action

```php
$categories = Category::pluck(‘name’, ‘id’)->toArray();
```

And in your view

```html
<select class="form-control form-select" name="category" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option value=""></option>
  @foreach($categories as $key => $category)
    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $name }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```